# How to delete .svn folder using FileZilla?

Tags: server, ftp, svn, filezilla

Recently I had uploaded a website to live server using FileZilla and by mistake i had uploaded that code with .svn folder.

I want to delete recursively those .svn folder using filezilla.

I don't have cpanel details or any ssh login details to client's server.

any idea to delete those folders using any filezella custome commands?

Answer (score 1):

`.svn` folder is hidden by default. You just have to make it visible (show hidden file/folders) in FileZilla than you can remove it accordingly.
See:

```
Version 2.x – View > Show hidden files
Version 3.x – Server > Force showing hidden files
```

I hope it will work.But if .svn folder doesn't appears in that case FileZilla cannot delete them because server doesn't show these file to ftp client.
Reference: [here](http://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=18412)